# Is there any way to test unique_together?

Tags: django

I am using class Meta to define some uniqueness for some Model. Is there any way I can test unique_together to see if it works?
I know in Ruby on Rails, if I failed to save some object to the database, save() will return False, but I don't find anything similar in Django.

```
class SiteBrand(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)  #should it be many to many?
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 200) #what is the code in sitebrand?
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("site", "code")
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Did you try to do this in Django? What happened?

Comment: I want to test the unique_together to see if it works

Comment: OK. So do that, and let us know what happens.

Comment: try it in the shell. (python manage.py shell)

Comment: my question is I don't know how to test that

Comment: Seriously? You want to test some functionality that prevents creating two items with the same "site" and "code" values. So, what might you do to test it..? (And this of course has **nothing at all** that is Django-specific.)

Comment: What's wrong with testing that? I think I don't understand what should be tested..

Answer (score 3):

You could try with something like:

```py
class LibrarycategoryTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_unique_together(self):
        site = 'just a site'
        code = 'just a code'

        # Create the original
        original = Sitebrand.objects.create(
            site=site,
            code=code
        )

        self.assertNotEquals(original, None)

        # Attempt to create a copy
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            original_clone = Sitebrand.objects.create(
                site=site,
                code=code
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a new python shell with:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then make sure you import your Sitebrand model:

```
from yourapp.models import Site, Sitebrand
```

And then try creating two models with the same site and code:

```
site = Site.objects.create( [the correct fields from Site here] )
Sitebrand.objects.create(name="first", site=site, code="yourcode")
Sitebrand.objects.create(name="second", site=site, code="yourcode")
```

You should get an error when you type the second row with the same site and code.

Comment: How to convert this into automated testing?

Comment: Use the exact same code but use https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises to catch the IntegrityError that get raised.